# Dependencies search result ended up in no result but when hardcored; it worked. Why?

Tags: android-studio, jackson, dependencies, bintray

I tried to add jackson dependancies in android studio, the dependencies search within the android studio returned some other libraries, but when i hardcored these dependencies it synced successfully. So basically the results came from rather than bintray.com ?

> compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.5'
>   compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.5'
>       compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.5'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that all the dependencies exist in [JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) (under bintray.com).
Here are the links in Jcenter to each of the dependencies you were looking for:

- [jackson-databind](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.fasterxml.jackson.core%3Ajackson-databind)
- [jackson-core](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.fasterxml.jackson.core%3Ajackson-core)
- [jackson-annotations](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.fasterxml.jackson.core%3Ajackson-annotations)

You can also see that the JCenter is updated until version 2.8.6.

Please check if your Android Studio is configured to get all its dependencies from JCenter.

I assume that maybe there is a mistake in the basic search you have made, so if you can provide us with more information it will be much more helpful.

In any case you can contact [JFrog Support](https://www.jfrog.com/support-service/support/) to get more helpful details.

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [[image]bintray](/questions/tagged/bintray) and [[image]artifactory](/questions/tagged/artifactory).</sup>